# VBA - Remove Seconds from NOW function

Tags: excel, vba, seconds

I have something that notify me an hour before it happens. For that, I use the NOW function in VBA as I need it to check for the Date as well.

The problem is the script runs every 20 seconds so I can't have it consider seconds for the NOW function.

Is there a way to remove those? To have only like (DAY,MONTH,YEAR,HOUR,MINUTE)?

Something along those lines:

```
 MyLimit = NOW(DAY,MONTH,YEAR,HOUR,MINUTE)

 For Each FormulaCell In FormulaRange.Cells
 With FormulaCell
            If .Value = MyLimit Then
            Call Notify
```

Here is the script in which I attempt to detect the date and time.

```
Option Explicit

Public Function AutoRun()
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:20"), "TaskTracker2"
End Function

Public Sub TaskTracker2()
Dim FormulaCell          As Range
Dim FormulaRange    As Range
Dim NotSentMsg      As String
Dim MyMsg           As String
Dim SentMsg         As String
Dim SendTo          As String
Dim CCTo            As String
Dim BCCTo           As String
Dim MyLimit         As Date


NotSentMsg = "Not Sent"
SentMsg = "Sent"
SendTo = Range("D2")
CCTo = Range("E2")
BCCTo = Range("F2")

MyLimit = Format((Now), "DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM")

Set FormulaRange = Range("E5:E35")
On Error GoTo EndMacro:
For Each FormulaCell In FormulaRange.Cells
    With FormulaCell
            If .Value = MyLimit Then
                MyMsg = SentMsg
                If .Offset(0, 1).Value = NotSentMsg Then
                    strTO = SendTo
                    strCC = CCTo
                    strBCC = BCCTo
                    strSub = "[Task Manager] Reminder that you need to: " & Cells(FormulaCell.Row, "A").Value
                    strBody = "Hello Sir, " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                        "This email is to notify that you that your task : " & Cells(FormulaCell.Row, "A").Value & " with the following note: " & Cells(FormulaCell.Row, "B").Value & " is nearing its Due Date." & vbNewLine & "It would be wise to complete this task before it expires!" & _
                        vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Truly yours," & vbNewLine & "Task Manager"
                    If sendMail(strTO, strSub, strBody, strCC) = True Then MyMsg = SentMsg

                End If
            Else
                MyMsg = NotSentMsg
            End If
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        .Offset(0, 1).Value = MyMsg
        Application.EnableEvents = True

    End With

Next FormulaCell
AutoRun

ExitMacro:
Exit Sub

EndMacro:
Application.EnableEvents = True

MsgBox "Some Error occurred." _
     & vbLf & Err.Number _
     & vbLf & Err.Description

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just round MyLimit to the nearest minute:

```
MyLimit = Round(Now * 1440, 0) / 1440
```

Consider, when comparing it to the contents of a cell, that you might need to use a `<=` or `>=` comparison to avoid problems if the time changes at the "wrong" time for an equality to hold true.

Comment: That worked Magic! Thanks I went through so many possibilities!

Comment: If I wanted to get the notification like 30 minutes before NOW, how would I do so?
I'm not really good at writing multiple modifications of a function :P

Comment: @FrancisMaltais Just add 30 minutes to `MyLimit` before you do the comparison.  30 minutes = 30/1440  or `Timeserial(0,30,0)`

Comment: So something like:  MyLimit = (Round(Now * 1440, 0) / 1440) - 30 / 1440 ?

Comment: @FrancisMaltais  You could, although for clarity I would use two lines; the first to Round MyLimit, and the second to add or subtract the 30 minutes.

Comment: Or a prettier variation: ((Round(Now * 1440, 0) - 30) / 1440)

Something like MyLimit = Round(Now * 1440, 0) / 1440 & MyLimit = MyLimit - 30/1440 ??

Answer (score 5):

To strip the seconds off `Now`, you can use some maths or to-and-from text conversion.

```
CDate(format(Now, "dd-mmm-yyyy hh:mm"))
'... or,
CLng(Now * 1440)/1440
```

Both of those return a true, numerical datetime value with the seconds stripped off. They do not average the seconds to the nearest minute; simply remove them.

Comment: I believe CLng does round (and rounds to the nearest even number)

Comment: You are indeed correct; I must have confused the results from several methods I tried.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jeeped, looks like this works too :)
I'll go with Ron's solution as he posted a little quicker and his works great too!
It's really appreciated!

Comment: @FrancisMaltais - No worries; there are a number of good ideas here. I would however question your definition of 'quicker' since my post was seven minutes prior to Ron's.

Comment: Ohh that's true, I misread the times. My bad D: Can I choose 2 best answers?

Comment: @FrancisMaltais - Don't worry about it. Often times identical results are produced by very different methods. Choose the one that makes sense to you.

Answer (score 3):

Another method would be this:

```
MyLimit = now-second(now)/60/60/24
```

second(now) returns the seconds, and the /60/60/24 converts it to days, which every date and time is stored in. Use this or Jeeped's answer, any one of these should work.

**Edit:**

To avoid the tiny but existing possibility of error, use this:

```
MyLimit = now
MyLimit =MyLimit -second(MyLimit)/60/60/24
```

Comment: Thanks :) It looks like it would work too! Really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Date function instead of the NOW function
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa227520(v=VS.60).aspx

UPDATE

Comment: When I do so, it fails to check for the time of the day :/

Comment: So if I use Date and my Reference Cell is per say 02/04/2016 - 4:02 PM, I get nothing. But it does work when only using the 02/04/2016 Date.

Comment: What about Format(NOW(), "dd/mm/yyyy - hh:mm AM/PM")

Comment: I get a Run-time error '13' - Type Mismatch when I attempt to MyLimit = Format((Now), "DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM")

Comment: Furthermore, the script doesn't trigger if I remove MyLimit and do: If .Value = Format((Now), "DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM")
Also, I took care to format the cells in range to a custom Format DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM

Comment: Dim MyLimit As Date  MyLimit  = Format(Now,"dd.mm.yy hh:mm AM/PM")

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help so far.
This modification fixes the compile error, but the script still doesn't send my notification when it should... I'll add the script below, maybe it will give you an idea. Updated in the main topic.

Answer (score 0):

Try limit = Format((Now), "DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM")

Comment: I get a Run-time error '13' - Type Mismatch when I attempt to MyLimit = Format((Now), "DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM")

Answer (score 0):

I usually just go with the function `=TIME(HOUR(NOW()),MINUTE(NOW()),0)`

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach per VBA Office 2010 and later:

```
 Dim DateWithoutSeconds : DateWithoutSeconds = DateAdd("s",-Second(Now),Now)
```

Notice that the minus (-) removes the seconds.

More info at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251759.aspx